# Crystal Reports 11 Compare All Data in Group to Specific Value

Tags: crystal-reports-2011

I have a crystal report I need to modify to leave out duplicate rows by "name".  So in Section Expert I am putting in a formula in Suppress and I cannot figure out how to compare the current name field being added to all the previous names that are in the group already.  I was trying to use the Filter() function, but for the String array parameters I don't know what to enter that would be all of the other names previously added to the group.  I need to compare the current name being added and see if it is already in the group so I can then compare another field called "date" and if the date of the field being added is more recent then the date of the duplicate name it will over write the row and only show the row with the most recent date.

Basically the question is how do I create an array with all the current fields already in the group(or does one exist already) so that I may use the Filter() function to see if the current name being added is already in that array of names added?

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out, so for anyone who runs into this here is my solution.

first off I made a formula in the "formula fields" section that creates two arrays when reading the data from the database and keeps only one copy of each id and date in the record.  Then for any other records that have the same id it will compare the date of that record to the record in the array with the same name and if the date is greater(later) then it will replace the date with the currently read in one.  I named this formula field idArray.

```
Global StringVar Array idArray;
Global DateVar Array expArray;
BooleanVar addName;
NumberVar x;
StringVar idTest;
StringVar expDateTest;

whilereadingrecords;
(
    addName := true;
    for x := 1 to Ubound(idArray) step 1 do
    (
        if({hrpersnl.p_empno} = idArray[x]) then
        (   
            addName := false;
            if(Date({nemphist.enddate}) > expArray[x]) then
                expArray[x] := Date({nemphist.enddate});
        )
    );

    if(addName = true) then
    (
        reDim Preserve idArray[Ubound(idArray) + 1];
        reDim Preserve expArray[Ubound(expArray) + 1];

        idArray[Ubound(idArray)] := {hrpersnl.p_empno};
        expArray[Ubound(expArray)] := Date({nemphist.enddate});
        //idTest := idTest + ' ' + {hrpersnl.p_empno};
        //expDateTest := expDateTest + ' ' + toText(Date({nemphist.enddate}));
    );

   //idTest
   //Ubound(idArray)
   //expDateTest
)
```

The commented out lines are what I used for testing to see how the arrays were building.  I left them in there just as an example of how to debug crystal reports, since it doesn't come with a debugger.

The next step is to create a record suppression formula.  In the Report menu I went to "section expert" and in the "Details" section of my group I clicked the little x-2 button next to the "Suppress (No Drill-Down)" option.  I then inserted this code that looks at the current record's id and date and if the id is in the first array it will take its position and use that to retrieve the date from the second array and if the current record's date is less than the date we now know to be the max then it will suppress the record.

```
Global StringVar Array idArray;
Global DateVar Array expArray;

NumberVar x;
BooleanVar suppress := false;

for x := 1 to Ubound(idArray) do
(
    if({hrpersnl.p_empno} = idArray[x]) then
        if(Date({nemphist.enddate}) < expArray[x]) then
            suppress := true;
);

if(suppress = true) then
    true
else
    false
```

Some lessons learned along the way...

1. Crystal Reports does global variables in a weird way.  It took me a few hours of fudging around with them to figure out that you can basically use them anywhere in the report as long as you declare them in each section you put them in with the Global [vartype] "name" syntax.  Even though you are re-declaring it each time Crystal does not remove the value of it or reset it or anything.
2. This operator ":=" is different than "=".  The ":=" operator is used to set values for variables whereas the "=" seems to be used only for comparisons.
3. Crystal reports is really weird with its design.  If you do want your formula field to return a specific variable or something you just type in that variable name without a ";" after it.  Anything without a ";" after it is considered the end of the formula.  So if you get this dumb "oh this code looks like its not part of the formula" error then it is because you didn't put a ";" after something and Crystal is assuming your function is ending at the location.  But if you don't put a variable without a ";" after it your formula with just return "false" by default.  So in my formula where I have       //idTest
     //Ubound(idArray)
     //expDateTest
   all I have to do is uncomment the variable I want to be returned and the formula will do so.

Comment: oh also I forgot to say this.  You need to drag that idArray formula field onto the report somewhere or it will never be called.  I just put the return of the formula to a blank StringVar and dragged the field onto the report somewhere out of the way.